# The default font of plot() function in R is italic and font.xxx doesn't work

Tags: r, plot, fonts

I simply created 2 sets of data and used plot() function, and everything in the figure is in italic, even though I have set the fonts into 1 (default). They are still in italic without font settings, except the title which would've been in bold.
[RStudio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tvff.jpg)

I tried to set the parameters to let them keep non-italic and obviously it didn't work. All other types of font works very fine (bold for 2, italic for 3, italic bold for 4 and Greek for 5).

Comment: Have you tried restarting R? Does this issue persist? Do you have any code that calls `par()` to changes any of the defaults there? I cannot replicate with the code provided.

Comment: Add `sessionInfo()` output to your question.

Comment: sessionInfo() output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3DFj4vrvT2/

Comment: Restarting R didn't work, and it's still like this after I tried to add par(font.axis = 1) (even though I haven't used par before). I suppose it has something to do with my system settings which are provided in the pastebin here.

Comment: Solved. It's not R's problem but my windows doesn't have Arial Regular. Use Win+X to wake up the powershell and type C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf and Enter and click install and everything's fine.